# Has he known yet what happened? / Has he known what happened yet?

Tags: present-perfect

> Has he known **yet** what happened?
>
> Has he known what happened **yet**?

I know "yet" is usually used in the end of questions, but in this case I suppose we need to use it after the main clause (see the first sentence). Right?

Or is it possible to use the second sentence too? What's the difference?

Comment: There is no reason why _yet_ has to go after the main verb, but both sentences would only be idiomatic with _Does he know?_ (or _has he found out?_).

Comment: What @KateBunting said. The "helper" verb in such contexts ***must*** be ***does*** coupled with the unmarked infinitive ***know***, not the Perfect construction ***has*** + Past Participle. It's somewhat "marked" (literary, poetic) to put adverbial ***yet*** immediately before the main verb ***know*** in such contexts. The idiomatic standards are ***Does** he **know** what happened **yet**?* and ***Does** he **know yet** what happened?* (which are equivalent and interchangeable).

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Could you explain (or give a link) why Present Perfect can't be used here with "know"? I haven't heard about this rule before. For example, I certainly can say: "I have known her for 10 years".

Comment: _I have known her for ten years_ is a different sense of _to know_ - 'be acquainted with'  - (_Connaitre_, if you have any French). Your sentence uses _know_ in the sense 'possess the information' (French _savoir_). We can say _He has known [the facts] since yesterday_, but it doesn't make sense to say _Has he [been in possession of the information] yet?_. That's why I suggested _found out_ as an alternative.